# WSS3 list lost its dispform association

Tags: sharepoint-designer, display-form

I have customized my DispForm, about 2 years ago, using SPD on my WSS3 site. I recently made an update, and now the association to the list is gone. All I did was modify a web part to include another field. If I type in the URL to my DispForm it works, but going to set the form in SPD as my DispForm, it doesn't work, and it's getting quite frustrating. Anyway I can force the association back??

Thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify wwhat you mean by setting the form in SPD as DispForm doesn't work? In SPD, can you open your list, select your custom DispForm, and click Set as Default in the ribbon?

Comment: Laurie: No ribbon in WSS3. :-) M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's now a KB article for the fix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000861

Answer (score 2):

Are you changing the Supporting Files for the list in the properties? Don't forget that you need to select the right Content Type (usually Item or Document).

Comment: To check the supporting files, right click on the list in SharePoint Designer -> Properties -> Supporting Files. Make sure the "Display item form" is set to your custom form.

Comment: Yes, I am specifying the suport files for the correct content type. I Click OK, then when I go back in, they're blank again. I've tried reverting back to an old copy of the dispform, which definitely worked then, and that can't join either.

Comment: The filenames are blank, or set to the defaults? In any case, you could set the supporting files programmatically, either using the Web Services or managed code. I've seen this happen before, but I can't tell you why.

Comment: I setup the code to change the URL to the DispForm, and it worked, the URL has been updated (I can see it in SPD and when reading the content type via code) BUT it still doesn't work. SP is showing the view url as http://wss/?ID=123

Comment: I snuck a fix in using JQuery, good enough for now
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").each(function() {
   var linkHref = this.href.toLowerCase();
   var url = '://' + window.location.hostname;
   url = url.toLowerCase();

   if(linkHref.indexOf(url + "/?id=") >= 0)
   {
    this.href="/projects/lists/projects/dispform.aspx" + linkHref.replace("http" + url + "/?","?");
   }
  });
 });

Comment: It's not always the "right" answer, but sometimes these little jQuery patches come in handy.